# Why does printing formatters in python differ when it's not all the same?

Tags: python, python-2.7

When I run this code

```
formatter = "%s %s %r %r"

print formatter % (1, 2, 3 , 4)
print formatter % ('one', 'two', 'three', 'four')
print formatter % (True, False, False, True)
print formatter % (formatter, formatter, formatter, formatter)
print formatter % (
   "I had this thing.",
   "That you could type up right.",
   "But it didn't sing.",
   "So I said goodnight."
)
```

The output of this line

```
print formatter % (formatter, formatter, formatter, formatter)
```

is

```
%s %s %r %r %s %s %r %r '%s %s %r %r' '%s %s %r %r'
```

Now I understand that in python we use %r for debugging reasons and specified formatters like %s for the user thats why the (' ') is added when %r is used.
What I don't understand is why is the only the first 2 without single quotes and not all of them?! How was that line executed briefly?

Comment: `__repr__` adds extra quotes to string. `__str__` doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%s` interpolates the result of `str()` on the object, while `%r` takes the output of `repr()` on the same object.

For strings, a *string literal syntax* is produced by `repr()`:

```
>>> s = 'foo bar'
>>> repr(s)
"'foo bar'"
>>> print(repr(s))
'foo bar'
```

That's because for the Python built-in objects, `repr()` will usually produce the *same syntax* that'll recreate the value. For integers or booleans, the `str()` and `repr()` versions just happen to look the same so you won't see a difference.

But when you interpolate `formatter`, a string, into `formatter` itself, you get two times the `str()` output, and two times the `repr()` output, and these differ.

Comment: I think I got it. So each formatter is executed individually that's why when it reached the third formatter which was %r, `repr()` was called. Am I correct?

Comment: @AhmedSamir: exactly.